# how to add audio track from video using @videogular/ngx-videogular/buffering lib

Tags: angularjs

Here is my component & html of angular js v15 the package im using is @videogular/ngx-videogular/buffering' i'm struggling to add audio track from video. i need controls or setting which is basis i can change the audio track from video. my video is dual audio supported video

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, Inject, OnInit, Renderer2, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-player',
  templateUrl: './video-player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-player.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class VideoPlayerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('media') videoPlayer: ElementRef<HTMLVideoElement> | undefined;

  video: any;
  videoUrl: string = "";
  videoType: string = "movie";
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { videoUrl: string, title: string, type: string },
    private renderer: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    console.log(data.videoUrl, "data.videoUrl");
    this.videoUrl = data.videoUrl;
    if (data.type) {
      this.videoType = data.type;
    }
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.videoPlayer) {
        const video = this.videoPlayer.nativeElement;
        if (video) {

          this.openVideoInFullscreen();
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {




  }


  videoPlayerInit(data: any) {
    console.log(data, "data")
    this.video = data;
    this.video.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.loadedMetadata.subscribe(this.initVdo.bind(this));
    //this.data.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.ended.subscribe(this.nextVideo.bind(this));
  }

  openVideoInFullscreen() {
    const videoElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.vg-icon-fullscreen');
    if (this.videoPlayer) {
      //const videoElement = this.videoPlayer.nativeElement;
      if (videoElement) {
        this.renderer.listen(videoElement, 'click', () => {
          this.initVdo();
        });

        videoElement.click();
      }
    }
  }
  initVdo() {
    if (this.video) {
    //  this.video.pause();
      if (this.video.requestFullscreen) {
        this.video.requestFullscreen();
      }
      else if (this.video.msRequestFullscreen) {
        this.video.msRequestFullscreen();
      }
      else if (this.video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        this.video.mozRequestFullScreen();
      }
      else if (this.video.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        this.video.webkitRequestFullScreen();
      }
    //  this.video.play();
    }

  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-player-wrapper">

  <vg-player *ngIf="videoType == 'movie'" (onPlayerReady)="videoPlayerInit($event)">
    <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
    <vg-buffering></vg-buffering>
    <vg-scrub-bar>
      <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
      <vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time></vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time>
    </vg-scrub-bar>
    <vg-controls [vgAutohide]="true" [vgAutohideTime]="1.5">
      <vg-play-pause></vg-play-pause>
      <vg-playback-button></vg-playback-button>
      <vg-time-display vgProperty="current" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
      <vg-scrub-bar style="pointer-events: none;"></vg-scrub-bar>
      <vg-time-display vgProperty="left" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
      <vg-time-display vgProperty="total" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>

      <vg-mute></vg-mute>
      <vg-volume></vg-volume>
      <vg-fullscreen></vg-fullscreen>
    </vg-controls>
    <video [vgMedia]="$any(media)" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto" playsinline webkit-playsinline autoplay
      crossorigin>
      <source [src]="videoUrl" type="video/mp4">

    </video>
  </vg-player>
  <vg-player *ngIf="videoType != 'movie'">

    <vg-buffering></vg-buffering>

    <vg-controls>
      <vg-play-pause></vg-play-pause>
      <vg-playback-button></vg-playback-button>
      <vg-time-display vgProperty="current" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
      <vg-scrub-bar style="pointer-events: none;"></vg-scrub-bar>


      <vg-mute></vg-mute>
      <vg-volume></vg-volume>
      <vg-fullscreen></vg-fullscreen>
    </vg-controls>
    <video [vgMedia]="$any(media)" [vgHls]="videoUrl" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto" playsinline
      webkit-playsinline autoplay crossorigin>


    </video>
  </vg-player>
</div>
<!-- ...working -->
```

Here is my component & html of angular js v15 the package im using is @videogular/ngx-videogular/buffering' i'm struggling to add audio track from video. i need controls or setting which is basis i can change the audio track from video. my video is dual audio supported video